# Springboot. ModelAndView addObject is not replace a tag

Tags: java, spring-mvc

My controller does not replace tags.

My controller has two endpoints URLs "/" and "/login"

> ```
> @Controller
> @RequestMapping(value={"/"})
> public class Index {
>     @GetMapping("/")
>     public ModelAndView getLoginPageId() {
>         return new ModelAndView("login");
>     }
>
>     @GetMapping("/index")
>     public ModelAndView getLoginPageId(
>             @RequestParam("login") String login,
>             @RequestParam("password") String password
>     ) {
>         ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("index");
>         modelAndView.addObject("message", "123");
>
>         return modelAndView;
>     }
> }
> ```

**login.jsp**

> ```
> <html>
> <head>
>
>     <title>login</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form name="newUser" action="/index" method="get">
>     Login:<br>
>     <input type="text" name="login"><br>
>     Password:<br>
>     <input type="text" name="password"><br>
>     <br>
>     <input type="submit" value="Login">
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

**index.jsp**

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
> <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
> </head>
> <body>
> <h1>My message ${message}</h1>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The Chrome browser gives response

> ```
> <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
> <head>
>     <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
>     <title>My Message ${message}</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <h1>HOA v ${message}</h1>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

The ${message} is not replaced. I'm expecting ${message} should be replaced to 123.
What do I need to change?

[image: Project structure]

Comment: What is your project structure? Where are your `.jsp`s located?

Comment: Please see attached picture

Comment: [Here](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-hello-world-example-jsp/) is an example of SpringBoot used with JSPs. Maybe you try to compare your solution to what you see there.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `<%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>` it will enable EL:

Have a look at:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

   <%@ page isELIgnored="false" %>

    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>My Message ${message}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>HOA v ${message}</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Alternatively you could add `<el-ignored>false</el-ignored>` to web.xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
<jsp-property-group>
    <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    <el-ignored>true</el-ignored>
  </jsp-property-group>
</web-app>
```